# Display mysql result the total of diffrent inputs

Tags: php, mysql

If i have a MYSQL table that sorts names and one table that sorts value.

Example this is how the table look like:

```
ID name   value
-- ------ -----
1  John     500
2  Rock     350
3  Wayne    700
4  John     350
5  Rock     250
6  Nick     100
7  Sweety    75
8  Lex      350
```

How do i display the total value for eache user? and also if i want to filter it to only show top 3 is there an easy command for that? Or do i need to make some kind of function.

In PHP

```
John 850
Wayne 700
Rock 600
Lex 350
Nick 100
Sweety 75
```

Answer (score 2):

It can be accomplished by the [aggregates](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum), kind of

```
SELECT ID, name, SUM(value) as total_score 
FROM user_scores 
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY total_score
```

Answer (score 2):

You need an aggregate function, specifically [`SUM`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum). You can order a query by any value in the select list, and to go high-to-low just use the `DESC` keyword:

```
SELECT Name, SUM(value) AS TotalValue
FROM myTable
GROUP BY Name
ORDER BY TotalValue DESC
```

The `AS TotalValue` will ensure that the column name is `TotalValue` when you reference it in PHP.